# How to get the selected item from a ComboBox in JavaFX?

Tags: combobox

i have ComboBox `cbx` and a TabPane Contains Tabs (tab: `t`) and a button `b1`. So on click on this button `b1`, it adds a new tab `t` in the TabPane and it adds a new item in the ComboBox `cbx` contains the same name of the tab. The problem is i don't know how to get the item from `cbx` and much the name of the item with the same name of the tab and then `Do something` so how i can do this with javafx and thanks very much :)

Answer (score 20):

Take a look at the API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html

There's a `comboBox.getValue()` method which gives you the selected item.

Comment: to mention: it's in the inherited class ComboBoxBase that's why people don't see it there (docs)

Answer (score 1):

To get the item selected by a user, use the `getValue()` method, you do that in an event handler that respond to a button click.

```
public void btnSelected()
{
String message = "You chose ";
message += cbo.getValue();
System.out.println(message, "Your Choice ");
}
```