# I cannot get a selection from a combobox

Tags: java, combobox

I'm writing a program with a combobox in which you can select different professors. After a selection is made you click a "GO" button and go to a new scene. However, the .getSelectedItem() method doesn't compile. If I use .getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() it runs but it doesn't work.

I've tried the .getItem() and .getValue() methods as well. I used to have the code all in one method but I need to pass it so I created a new method that is called from the method with the event. I also tried calling the method from the method with the "GO" button.

These are the two methods to get the selection:

```
public void InstructorSelected(ActionEvent event)
{

    String instructorSelected = determineSelection();
    System.out.println(instructorSelected);

}
public String determineSelection()
{

    String selection = combobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    return selection;

}
```

And here is the event method that loads the third scene when you click the second "GO" button:

```
public void goToCourseViewButtonPushed(ActionEvent event) throws IOException 
{
        Parent CourseViewParent = 
        FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CourseView.fxml"));
        Scene CourseViewScene = new Scene (CourseViewParent);

        Stage CourseWindow = (Stage) 
        ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        CourseWindow.setScene(CourseViewScene);
        CourseWindow.show();
}
```

I need to get the selection and store it a variable because I then need to use it to get data from a database but only the ones for that professor.
If use this methods the program gets stuck when I try to load a new scene.
However, if instead of getting the selection from the combobox I just pass a String then it works fine so the problem isn't with loading the other scene.

Comment: Do you get an Error when click the "GO" Button?
Did you try to System.out.print(combobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()) when the ComboBox Click Event happens? What is the output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the selected item from a ComboBox in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572918/how-to-get-the-selected-item-from-a-combobox-in-javafx)

Comment: Hi. Yes i tried printing out the selection from the combo box and it prints fine, that's what I don't get. When you click the "GO" button a new scene is loaded, there you select a term (Spring or Fall) using radio buttons and there's a new "GO" button to a third scene. This second "GO" button is the one that has an error loading the third scene. But I know there's not an error in the code to load the third scene and in fact it works if I don't use the method that gets the selection.

Comment: What is the Error? Post the Stacktrace please.
So it works with every other String then the one you get from the ComboBox?

Comment: Yes, if I just say String instructor = "paul";  instead of getting it from the combobox it works. I'll post the error in the question

Comment: Sorry I couldn't post it above but here's what I get when the second "GO" button is clicked. There's many more lines but I cannot post all of it:    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at

Comment: When you call  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CourseView.fxml")). The Controller gets called and your variable selection is set to Null again most likely. Do you have two different Controller or just one? You need to pass the variable in another way if that happens.

Comment: I have one controller for each scene. How do  I stop it from setting the variable to null again?

Comment: No its something different. Sorry i can't help you.

Comment: Don't worry. I've also asked classmates and even sat down with my professor for 2 hours and no one knows how to fix it. I'll just have to give up on this project and hope I can pass the class.